# Ошибки при компиляции библиотеки wxwidget

Tags: c++

При компиляции 22-х проектов библиотеки wxwidget выдаёт

> `Build: 20 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped`

Как это исправить? (Тип компиляции: Realis, среда разработки: Visual Studio 2010, C++.)

**Дополнено.**

Вот последнее, что выдаёт Visual Studio 2010.

> `22>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1151,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-2.9.2\build\wx291_msw_vc10\..\..\lib\vc_lib\wxregex.lib) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-2.9.2\lib\vc_lib\wxregexu.lib). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).`
>
> `22>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1153,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(wxregex) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (wxregexu). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).`
>
> `22>  wx_vc10_wxregex.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files\wxWidgets-2.9.2\build\wx291_msw_vc10\..\..\lib\vc_lib\wxregex.lib`
>
> `========== Rebuild All: 20 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: Найти эти два проекта с ошибками, посмотреть ошибки и попытаться исправить? либо скопировать текст ошибки. Если это единственное сообщение - тогда попробовать сделать полный ребилд (что типа Rebuild All)

Comment: Rebuild solution не помог.

Comment: судя по всему, загвоздка в библиотеке регулярных выражений. Где то что то не так с "юникодом" (похоже, что программа сама не в юникоде и хочет неюникодную версию библиотеки, а студия пытается слинковать с юникодной, но может и наоборот).

Answer (score 1):

У вас мисматч используемых библиотек *(`wxregexu.lib`, `wxregexu.lib`)*, предположительно для `Unicode` и `ANSI` версий библиотек соответственно.

*В таком случае можно либо сделать что-нибудь в духе `#define WX_UNICODE` в настройках проекта, либо руками указать, какую именно версию библиотеки стоит применять.*